# How does Linux system handle CRLF in a file?

Tags: c, linux, compilation

I know CR LF (\r\n) would be interpreted as two characters, "carriage return" + "new line", but how would that affect different programs when it's for example, a source code--

1. As a bash script to be executed?
2. As a source code to be compiled? For example, .c file?

Comment: Both carriage-return and newline are considered white-space characters. And how those are handled depends very much on the language. In none of the languages you mention (Bash script and C) white-space is relevant or significant, except as part of quoted strings.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude nit pick: Newline does have a tiny bit more significance than just being whitespace.  It also indicates the end of a preprocessor directive and there should also be one at the end of the source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Shell script

The shell does not treat CR as white space by default.

Source code (`crlf67.sh`) with CR marked by `^M`:

```
#!/bin/sh^M
^M
echo "Hello^M
World!"^M
```

Running the command explicitly:

```
$ sh crlf67.sh
: command not found
Hello
World!
$ sh crlf67.sh 2>&1 | vis -r
crlf67.sh: line 2: ^M: command not found
Hello^M
World!^M
$
```

(The `vis` command is an extended version of the `vis` program from 
Brian W Kernighan, Rob Pike
[The Unix Programming Environment](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/013937681X) (Nov 1983).  It makes non-printing characters visible.)

If you make the script executable:

```
$  make crlf67
cat crlf67.sh >crlf67 
chmod a+x crlf67
$ crlf67
-bash: ./crlf67: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
$
```

The kernel doesn't treat the CR as white space either and fails to find the command.

#### C source code

In C source code, officially, you can't use backslash to continue lines in C if the line ending is CRLF because the character after the backslash isn't a newline (NL or LF); it's a CR.  Some compilers will ignore white space (at least the CR) after the last backslash on a line — GCC 9.1.0 for one, but also earlier versions.  It warns about spaces after a trailing backslash (unless you use `-Werror` as I do; then it's an error).  It isn't what the standard stipulates; however, even `-pedantic` doesn't stop it ignoring the erroneous notation.

Source code (`crlf19.c`) with CR marked by `^M` and newline marked by `^J`:

```
#include <stdio.h>^M^J
^M^J
int main(void)^M^J
{^M^J
    printf("Hello\   ^M^J
 world!\   ^M^J
\n");^M^J
    return 0;^M^J
}^M^J
```

Compilation by GCC 9.1.0 on macOS 10.14.5 Mojave:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic crlf19.c -o crlf19 
crlf19.c: In function ‘main’:
crlf19.c:5:18: warning: backslash and newline separated by space
    5 |     printf("Hello\
      |                   
crlf19.c:6:8: warning: backslash and newline separated by space
    6 |  world!\
      |         
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror crlf19.c -o crlf19 
crlf19.c: In function ‘main’:
crlf19.c:5:18: error: backslash and newline separated by space [-Werror]
    5 |     printf("Hello\
      |                   
crlf19.c:6:8: error: backslash and newline separated by space [-Werror]
    6 |  world!\
      |         
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
$
```

This behaviour goes back at least as far as GCC 4.1.2 — that version was tested on an ante-diluvian RHEL 5 box.

If you remove the spaces after the backslash leaving just the CRLF line endings, GCC doesn't complain at all.

Answer (score 3):

As it is a sequence of whitespace characters, CRLF is ignored in C, but not in Bash:

If the first line of a bash script (`#!/bin/bash`) has a CRLF line terminator, the script won't run. It will be looking for the file `/bin/bash\r`, which doesn't exist.

If any of the other lines of a script have a CRLF line terminator, the command on that line will either be not found (as bash is looking for a command named `some_command\r`), or will be passed a `\r` at the end of its last parameter.

Comment: That's not quite correct. Most shells (I've tried, sh, bash, and ksh) don't treat CR as white space. If a line in a shell script is "some_command^M", where "^M" is a CR character, it will try to execute a command whose name is literally `"some_command\r"`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the program that's processing the file. I don't believe there's any general rule.

For example, I just created several shell scripts in an otherwise empty directory. One of them is named `some_command` with an ASCII CR as the last character of the file name.

I can invoke that command from a shell script by including that CR as part of the command name. The shell (sh, bash, or ksh) doesn't treat the CR character as white space.

```
$ ls -l
total 16
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kst kst 26 Jul  1 16:46  crlf.bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kst kst 25 Jul  1 16:46  crlf.ksh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kst kst 24 Jul  1 16:46  crlf.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kst kst 21 Jul  1 16:49 'some_command'$'\r'
$ cat -v crlf.bash
#!/bin/bash
some_command^M
$ cat -v crlf.ksh
#!/bin/ksh
some_command^M
$ cat -v crlf.sh
#!/bin/sh
some_command^M
$ cat -v some_command
#!/bin/sh
echo hello
$ ./crlf.bash
Hello
$ ./crlf.ksh
Hello
$ ./crlf.sh
Hello
$
```

The version of `ls` I'm using (GNU coreutils 8.28) has a special syntax for showing file names that contain special characters. `cat -v` shows CR characters as `^M`.